# (C Programming) How to find the most frequent occurring digit in long numbers without using array?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, conditional-statements

Input Format:
A single line that contains an integer.

Constraint:
(-) each element <= 9223372036854775807 and >= 0

Input Sample:
3214144

Output Format:
A single line that contains the most frequent occurring digit. It is guaranteed that there's only one such digit.

Output Sample:
4

Here's the code that I made:

```
int main(){
int input, i=0, num=0;
do{
    scanf("%i", &input);
    i=input%10;   
    break;
}while(input<= 9223372036854775807 && input>=0);
if (i+i==i*2){
    num+=1;
}
else{
    num=0;
}
if (num>0){
    printf("%i", i);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: plsss i'm losing my mind over this it's been a day

Comment: Covert the number to a string and then loop over the characters in the string.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense in fundamental ways. `break` exits the loop immediately so that loop only ever runs one iteration. And why would you have `scanf` in a loop anyway? Can you please describe the algorithm you are trying to implement because I really can't tell from that code?

Comment: Actually,  you should take the input in as a string..  don't read it in as an int.

Comment: If you can't use an array make 10 variables - one for the count of each digit.  Then loop through and update one of the variables depending on what digit it is.

Comment: That number seems a tad on the high side for an int and, if read as a string, that's a char array and so violates the requirement constraints. Ask your prof/TA which big number library it recommends.

Comment: hello i finally got it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The chars in the [asciitable][1] can be treated as integers.  The char '0' is the number 48.  '9' is 48+9 (i.e.57).

'9' - '0' = 57 - 48 = 9.

Treat the characters that you read as integers.  Make an array to hold the 10 values.  Afterwards, the index of the number with the biggest number is your solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char c;
    int counts[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int max = 0;

    while(c=getc(stdin)){
        /* read until we get a newline */
        if (c=='\n') break;

        /* you can treat a char as an integer */
        counts[c-'0']++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(counts[i] > counts[max]) max=i;
    }
    printf("%i is the max",max);


    return 0;
}
```

Also consider that the maximum value for a 32 bit int is 2147483647 while a string can be unlimited.
[1]: https://www.asciitable.com